# Create Parse installation object UWP winjs

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, winjs, uwp

I'm using Parse javascript SDK in my UWP javascript application. As mentioned in the quickstart, I'm initializing Parse with following line,

```
Parse.initialize("App_ID", "Javascript_Key");
```

but it does not create installation object in Parse dashboard. Also, as mentioned in docs,

> Installation data can only be modified by the client SDKs, the data browser, or the REST API.

I'm trying to follow some answer to create installation object, here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599778 but I'm not able to get it working. Any ideas on how to create installation object? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to generate a "native" installation id for your device. You can probably use the one already generated by the Parse javascript platform, but it's not hard to generate a new one. Just mimic what's already been done in the Parse source code:

```
function generateInstallationId(){
    function hexOctet() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    return hexOctet() + hexOctet() + '-' + hexOctet() + '-' + hexOctet() + '-' + hexOctet() + '-' + hexOctet() + hexOctet() + hexOctet();
}
```

Then construct the proper xhr headers. Since we are mimicking the way a native Parse SDK uses REST, we use the dotNet key or the client key, not the javascript key.

```
var xhrHeaders = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": YOUR_APP_ID,
    "X-Parse-Windows-Key": YOUR_DOTNET_KEY
};
```

Then construct your installation object data so that it would pass server validation.

```
var installationData = {
   appIdentifier: "your.app.package",
   appName: "appName",
   appVersion: "1.0.0",

   deviceType: "winrt",
   deviceUris: {_Default: YOUR_WNS_CHANNEL_URI},
   timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
   localeIdentifier: "en-US",
   parseVersion: "1.7.0.0",
   installationId: generateInstallationId()
}
```

Finally, make the REST call

```
WinJS.xhr({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/installations",
    headers: xhrHeaders,
    data: JSON.stringify(installationData)
});
```

I plucked most of this code from [parse-push-plugin](https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin), particularly [this file](https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin/blob/master/src/windows/ParsePushPluginProxy.js). If you need more context or want to see how the WNS channel is obtained, feel free to look there.